# Path in Maven import being overriden by main project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, filepath

I've got two Maven projects **A** and **B**. I'm packaging project A as a jar and adding it as a dependency in project B. Project A shows up in my External Libraries (using IntelliJ) and I can see all the source code and files.

In project A I've got a method that is retrieving the files in a folder located at *projectB/src/main/resources/folder/*, and I'm using the following code to check whether any files exist within this folder:

```
File folder = new File("src/main/resources/folder/");
File[] defaultDefinitions = folder.listFiles();
```

This works correctly when project A is ran. However, when project B calls this method, instead of appending the path to project A's working directory, it is appending it to project B's, and obviously there are no files located at *projectA/src/main/resources/folder/*.

How does one go about solving this issue?

Comment: Your base directory (`.`) is `projectB`. And when you run project it search in `src/main/resources/folder/`. Instead of it try to search in resources: `MyClass.class.getResourcesAsStream('"folder/<myFile>")`

Answer (score 0):

Don't load Maven resources from the filesystem API :

```
File folder = new File("src/main/resources/folder/");
```

It will work only during the development phase as you have the source code besides the running application.

Instead, use the classloader :

```
File folder = getClass().getResource("/folder").toURI().toURL().getFile();
```

It will work as `src/main/resources` is a "special" directory for Maven as all resource files located in this directory are added in the classpath at compile time and will be also available in the classpath at runtime.

Note that you could retrieve the File from a less convoluted way by using the java.nio API :

```
Path folderPath = Paths.get(getClass().getResource("/folder").toURI());
Stream<Path> pathStream = Files.list(folderPath);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however the code above did not work. Maybe I was not clear, but my problem is due to the fact that I am attempting to read the contents of files stored within a jar. I've tried all the solutions I could find online, as well as anything else that made sense to me, yet I cannot manage to do this.

A NullPointerException is constantly thrown from my main application. I can read the contents of a specific file if its path is hardcoded, however I wish to dynamically read the contents of all files in the /resources directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that you're using a relative path, and you're relying on working directories (automatically managed by the IDE). You need to read files in a way that's going to be predictable, even if you run your code outside the IDE.

You can solve the problem by using absolute paths, which is going to help even if you run the program from the command line, or anywhere outside the IDE:

```
String path = "/absolute/path/from/properties/etc/folder/";
              //better use a program argument or properties file for this

File folder = new File(path);
```

Comment: What with runtime? If you deploy project to the server?

Comment: If this is something deployed to a server, then you can use properties files for configuration, or you can use a database for configuration, or you can start your server with JVM properties, etc. The point is to externalize the config so that the path can be passed to you at runtime, instead of being dependent on the working directory.